# How to display questions stored in list in fragments in android

Tags: android

I am creating a quiz app in which I am storing questions in Arraylist but now I have to display them using fragments but I am not able to figure out how to display questions stored in arraylist in fragment
below is the code

this is the database code

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("What is JP?","Jalur Pesawat", "Jack sParrow", "Jasa Programmer", "Jasa Programmer");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("where the JP place?", "Monas, Jakarta", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bantul", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bandul", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bantul");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("who is CEO of the JP?","Usman and Jack", "Jack and Rully","Rully and Usman", "Rully and Usman" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("what do you know about JP?", "JP is programmer home", "JP also realigy home", "all answer is true","all answer is true");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("what do you learn in JP?","Realigy","Programming","all answer is true","all answer is true");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

and this is the code of main activity in which I should make change

```
 package com.example.android.viewpager4;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    {


        private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
            initialisePaging();
        }

        private void initialisePaging()
        {
            List<Fragment> fragments =new Vector<Fragment>();

             mPagerAdapter= new com.example.android.viewpager4.PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
             ViewPager pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
             pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        }
    }
```

and this is the xml layout in which I have to display question with radio button as options

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity" 
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right. Only change you need is to Create our own list of fragments and provide it your PagerAdapter.

```
List<Fragment> fragments =new Vector<Fragment>();
```

change to

```
List<CustomFragment> fragments =new Vector<CustomFragment>();
```

Now for CustomFragment use the xml which you have specified above and pass the question as parameter.

Something like

```
  fragments.add(CustomFragment.newInstance(question1));

  fragments.add(CustomFragment.newInstance(question2));
```

and so on

> Kindly note that this will not be the best possible solution because you are creating objects of all the fragments at once. Instead consider creating your own FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: can you be more specific and tell in detail about how to implement custom fragments or can you please explain it by making changes in the code

Comment: hey man please help me and tell me how to implement custom fragments

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html - Instead of ArticleFragment name for your fragment will be CustomFragment. Inflate the xml which you intent to use for questions in this fragment onCreateView.